# How to create new postgreSQL rows to save data every time you run your django code

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm, web-development-server

I have a doubt now when I execute my script I am able to save it in a row

### **My models.py  has 2 tables ( or class) Page and Category**

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)



    def __unicode__(self):
```

### return self.title

**This code is a snip from my views.py**

---

```
Category.objects.all()
f = Category()
Page.objects.all()
p = Page()
p.category = f

x = India(symb)

f.name = x['Company Name']
f.save()


p.category = f
p.title = symb
p.price = float(x['Price'])
p.save()
```

---

when I execute it again or everytime , it overwrites the same row which makes sense the way I used it.

**How do I create new row every time I run my script so that I can save new data in a new row instead of overwriting the same row**

I thought of using python 'random' to pick a random letter from a list (g for example) everytime I run the script then join it to get something like 'g.price' but then this has limitation of 26 letters , random but not unique so same letters can be generated ( though I can do a 'if' check on that).

**Is there an easy and proper way to do this.?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models.py:-

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)



    def __unicode__(self):
```

views.py:-

If you want to update page of particular category follow this:-

```
a = Category.objects.get(name=nameField) #Fetch reference object for which category name you want to add page

x = India(symb)

b = Page.objects.filter(name=a).update(title=symb,price = float(x['Price']))
```

If you want to add new category and page both follow this:-

```
x = India(symb)

a = Category.objects.create(name = x['Company Name']) 

b = Page.objects.create(name=a,title=symb,price = float(x['Price']))

b.save()
```

Comment: I think this will work, I will try this today.
so, I also give a.save() and b.save() , right ?  and every time I add a new category , it would save into a new row and not overwrite ?

Comment: Thank you! That helped!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it isn't inserting them by default, but you can force Django to do so.
As official documentation suggests:

> In some rare circumstances, it’s necessary to be able to force the save() method to perform an SQL INSERT and not fall back to doing an UPDATE. Or vice-versa: update, if possible, but not insert a new row. In these cases, you can pass the force_insert=True or force_update=True parameters to the save() method. Obviously, passing both parameters is an error: you cannot both insert and update at the same time!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update

Comment: so you're saying that I need not use a new variable to save it in a new row ? eg:
p.title --> goes into row1
should I use a.title --> to save it in another row?

Comment: @sujithjohn, could you please post your models here? Maybe there is some issue with the primary key